# How to transfer values/data between 2 programming languages?

Tags: python, c#, c++, exe

suppose I create a program in c++
and create an .exe by the name of ctesting.exe

```
 #include<iostream> //ctesting code
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "enter number=";
    cin >> n;
    return n+1;//this value is returned to the program that executed ctesting.exe
}
```

and now i create another program in c# (or any other language,preferably python)
how do i run the ctesting.exe and get value (n+1) from it and possibly even supply a value to the ctesting.exe before it runs i.e. replace the cin>>n with input coming directly from the c# program(or any other language)

```
namespace c_hash_testing 
{
    class Primary
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
           var data=some_run_function("ctesting.exe");
           //data is assigned n+1
        }

    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to programming but aren't numbers/strings raw data? like can't we transfer them between programs using ONLY inbuilt functions and not having to use any type of file to transfer data between them?
and if such a thing is possible could someone make a list of programing languages and their respective functions in order to achieve this?

Comment: It's called inter-process communication (IPC): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: It's called command line arguments, or standard input/output streams, or TCP, or RPC, or remoting, or named pipes, or webservices, or rest, or environment variables, or...

Comment: IPC and then you can use something like protobuf (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf) to pack your data in a meaningful way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have two pieces of code written in different languages to communicate with each other. There are multiple ways to do so, but most of them are a little too complex to grasp for someone who is new to programming, so here is my advise.

The easiest way to achieve this is by not having two separate programs, but building your feature into a library that is loaded into the main program. The library and the main program can be written in two different languages, but the library has to be of a specific type depending on your operating system.

There are two kinds of libraries :

- Static libraries are embarked into your executable when the build is done successfully, meaning your program does not depend on anything aside from your .exe file. Also, using your lib's feature is as straightforward as calling the functions.
- Dynamic libraries are not embarked in your executable. You have to provide them with your .exe file, otherwise your program will fail. You may already know these libraries as DLL (the name of the extension). Using these libs are not as straightforward as calling the functions, because you have to manually load the library and look for functions. So I wouldn't advise a beginner to chose this option.

You can get more info by searching how to build and use a static library or a dynamic library for your operating system on your IDE.

Comment: so basically creating a library in any language can be used  to call functions/variables in other languages?

Comment: A library is like a black box of features, your main program doesn't care how it has been made, so yes

Comment: could you provide some reliable source on how to read/create libraries for c# c++ & python

Comment: This depends on your operating system and IDE, if you're using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows you can rely on Microsoft's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-160) for C++ and C#. Python being an interpreted language may not compile into a library, but I'm no expert in that language, I'll let you do your own research